# C++ object creation

Tags: c++, oop

I have doubt in creating objects in C++.
Say I have a class called Employee with some data members and methods.

Now in main function  sometimes I have seen developers using different methods to create objects like

```
Employee emp1;                // 1)
Employee emp2 = new Employee  // 2)
```

My doubt is when we should use case 1 and when to use option 2.

Comment: I think you mean:  2) Employee *emp2 = new Employee

Comment: It depends on how you want to manage the lifetime of the object.

Comment: @dreamlax - however you want to manage the lifetime, samprats syntax won't work. You can't assign an `Employee*` value (as returned by `new Employee`) to an `Employee` variable - unless you define some kind of very implausible cast, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Employee emp1;

This creates a default constructed employee at the stack. Its lifetime lasts until it goes out of scope.

> 2) Employee emp2 = new Employee

This probably doesn't even compile, I guess you meant:

> 2) Employee *emp2 = new Employee

This creates a default constructed employee at the heap, and assigns its address to an employee pointer. Its lifetime lasts until `delete` its called on it.

They are two complete different things. Until you learn more about it, you probably want to stick with the first version. Once you learn more about it, you should stick with the first version as well unless you know and understand the reasons not to.

Comment: (1) may not be on the stack. Better wording would be. `This creates a default constructed employee object.`

Comment: @LokiAstari: Where else would the object be constructed if not on the stack or heap? Are you saying that `Employee emp1` may actually be allocated on the heap for some reason?

Comment: @Loki Astari: You got my attention! How could it not be in the stack? Note the OP said "in main function".

Comment: @Shakedown - if you use the syntax as a member definition in a class or struct, the member will be constructed wherever the class-instance is constructed - and that may well be on the heap. That syntax can also be used for global variables, which are neither on the heap nor the stack. However, if it's a local variable declaration in a function (as context suggests), then it's certainly on the stack.

Comment: @K-ballo: OK you got me I was thinking the general case where objects can be instide other objects (so its location is relative to its context). (But you are assuming there is a stack :-) ). But there is no stack. Personally I find it makes C++ hard to reason about if you think in terms of stack and heap (these are java constructs anyway). In C++ if you think about everything in terms of lifespan (as the standard does) it makes reasoning about everything much simpler.

Comment: @Loki - Stack and heap are Java concepts??? No no no... Stack (in this context) was originally a machine-code concept, and heap is a data-structure concept from *way* back. If anything, the distinction is *more* relevant in C++ because it's relevant to performance issues and correctness issues (e.g. dangling pointers).

Comment: @Steve314: There is no requirement for a stack in C++ (check the standard). Also I have an implementation hardware that does not even have memory let alone a stack ([Dataflow architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow)). The term stack/heap used in this context was brought over from the Java world which is how it was defined. Though Java inherited the stack from the machine code world (as do most languages).

Comment: @Loki - the C++ standard leaves lots of details undefined. In practice, though, local variables, parameters and function return addresses live on the stack. I was discussing stacks and heaps, and working with them in assembler, long before Java was invented. Show me a standards-compliant C++ compiler that works on a platform that doesn't have memory and I'll be very impressed.

Comment: @Steve314: But I don't want to get drawn out into an argument about stack and heap (that's not the important point). In my personal opinion. Thinking about these terms makes it harder to understand C++ and its object model. Thinking of objects in terms of `lifespan` is what I am trying to get at, and is much more productive; and makes the concepts easier to grasp.

Comment: @Steve314: That's easy. I worked on DataFlow machine that had a C++ compiler. It has no memory (in the standard conventional way of thinking about it) it definitely did not have a stack (as there was no memory). Objects are objects. passed from node to node in the dataflow graph. I provided a link above.

Comment: @Loki - lifespan is certainly important, agreed. Part of my point is that it's more important in C++ than in Java. You can't get dangling pointers (to objects, at least) in Java because, even for local variables, the object can outlive the function and the GC (usually) sorts out the lifetime for you.

Comment: @Loki - I've used dataflow based design at least, though not hardware. The C++ language has these things called variables, though - you're telling me this architecture can remember variable values without having a memory? Don't forget - even registers are a kind of memory, and some processors have enough of them that they are treated like a stack for - you know - local variables, parameters and return addresses.

Comment: There are no addresses (in the conventional terms) in dataflow. Everything is data and flows between nodes. As such you do not need memory and there is no such thing as a return address (as there is no memory) for instructions. Data flows between nodes nodes are the instructions data flows between them. No need for a stack (mostly because the concept would break datalfow as everything is done in parallel having a stack would break the parallelism). You are too stuck in thinking about conventional architectures and processors. The closest you have to address is a links in the graph.

Comment: There are no local variables (as data flows across the nodes). Everything can be though of as parameters as they parameters are the inputs to the nodes. The result of the node is data and the next node in the graph that it must flow too.

Comment: Case 2) doesn't need to be on any "heap", either. We don't know if there's a member `operator new()` and what it does.

Comment: Sigh.  Case 1) has "automatic" storage duration as opposed to "static" storage duration.  "automatic" means different things in different contexts.  If it is in the scope block of a function, then the object goes away at the end of scope.  If it is a member of a class, it goes away after the destructor for the class has completed.  If it is at global scope, it goes away at program termination.

Comment: I agree with @Loki, whether or not the hardware implements a "stack" and a "heap", I think it's more important to understand the lifespan of statically and dynamically allocated memory.  However, if there is a limit (other than total physical memory) on stack/heap space, then obviously that's something to keep in mind.  Otherwise, decisions about which type of allocation to use can be made based upon the lifespan of the result, I think.

Comment: @Loki - I'm pretty surprised, I have to admit. I could still make arguments that C++ was originally designed to work with a stack-based architecture and that, based purely on the assumption of Turing-completeness, any model can be translated by a compiler to any other - that just because the standard avoids specifying a stack doesn't mean that the compiler isn't in effect emulating a stack-based architecture. I might also suggest that there must be a fair amount of "memory" in the dataflow channels (sent but not yet received) to handle any significant application. But that's just nit-picking.

Comment: @Steve: Unfortunately we have two generation that have been brought up with stack/heap is how computers are made. Which has locked our society into a way of thinking that prevents thinking of new alternative approaches to solving problems at the hardware level. I for one am glad that the C/C++ standard was designed the way it is (thus allowing some thought outside the box). Also I am sure C/C++ was originally designed knowing the stack exists its hard to think about computers in another way (see even I am stuck in this thinking).

Comment: As for memory; I also have several Tera bytes floating around my head, but it is not addressable in the same way that memory is addressable in a computer. Dataflow is the same way (there is memory) but it is not memory in the conventional sense (as stack and heap or even addressable at the instruction level). Though data is made available to the nodes for execution just like impulses flow into my synapses.

Comment: @Loki - I'm not sure. When I finally accepted what you were saying I went through a bit of a paradigm shift, but I'm kinda shifting back now. There was some of it in my last comment - in C++, the lifetimes of function-calls, parameters and local variables are Last-In-First-Out - they *are* a stack. Accessing items that aren't the current top-of-stack is a form of relative addressing. Explicit or not, the stack-machine layer of abstraction is still there, and whether that model is supplied by the hardware or emulated by the compiler isn't important, at least from a certain POV.

Comment: @Steve: I see no need for a stack in dataflow parameters are just data flowing to nodes. This is the problem with having several generations of programmers stuck with a particular style of architecture. It becomes nearly imposable for you visualize anything different. What you are having a conceptual problem with is how to visualize multiple reuses of the same piece of the graph. This is known as colouring in dataflow (note this is nothing like a stack). But you should be able to find articles on data colouring.

Comment: The problem with dataflow is not the lack of a stack but the inherent unbound parallelism that is caused by a system were everything can be executed in parallel. We have not reached the technological level where dataflow is practical as we can only scale to systems of 100's of parallel execution not 100's of billion. Note: I am sure there are other problems that we as yet do not even comprehend to exist with this architecture mainly because we can't even execute a basic system on anything but the most simple of problems.

Comment: @Loki - if you're using a language based on that dataflow architecture, and with no trace of a stack-machine layer of abstraction, that might be much more interesting from a programming paradigms POV. Otherwise, it's a bit like hardware associative memories - an implementation detail that could just as easily be handled with software, possible performance issues aside.

Comment: But this is why off topic. My original point is. Thinking of terms of stack and heap (for beginners) is determinant in C++. The only clean way to think about objects is in terms of lifespan. Automatic objects have a lifespan in relation to their parent context. Nothing else is important.

Comment: There are already compilers that will compile C and C++ to dataflow architectures. (C was much much easier)

Comment: @Loki - that's not my point. I mean the paradigm that the source code describes. Compilation is translation - the implementation hardware model isn't the same as the paradigm you're thinking in when you write the source code. If you're thinking in C++, you're not thinking in a pure dataflow paradigm - the LIFO is implicitly built into the rules of the language, irrespective of the hardware model you translate it to. My original comment was about a way of thinking about C++, and not intended for compiler-writers. "Stack" summarizes the collective behaviour of quite a few C++ lifetime rules.

Comment: @Steve314: That's my point: **the stack concept** does not summarize any behavior. It is a crude and inaccurate approximation that covers only a fraction of the behavior. And thus by thinking like this you are causing young inexperienced developers to think incorrectly about lifespan.

Comment: @Loki - it's not inaccurate, only incomplete - ie it doesn't cover heap lifetimes (though even heap-allocated objects follow the LIFO pattern for member construction/destruction). It summarizes many rules in the standard. The standard AFAIK leaves the pattern that unifies them left unstated. However, just because one particular pattern is insufficient to describe everything, doesn't mean it isn't useful to explain what it does describe.

Comment: @Steve314: My assertion it is not only un-usefull (it does not even cover stack lifetime correctly/completely). I contend it is in fact harmful (as anecdotal evidence caused by this misconception causes a lot of useless questions on SO). If we stick to what the standard says. Then all these problems go away.